# Suitable prepositions between "doctoral program" and "university"?

Tags: prepositions

I wrote "Why I apply to a given doctoral program at a given university" but am unsure of the use of "at". What are the natural prepositions between "doctoral program" and "university" then?

Comment: context...context...context

Comment: By "context" do you mean something like what after my editting?

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Comment: Thanks, so what are the natural prepositions? Is "at" suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 'at' is a suitable and commonly used preposition between 'doctoral program' and 'university'.

For example:

> I am applying for the (doctoral program) **at** (given university).

An alternative wording that I have seen in a few places, is to use the word 'through', for example:

> I am applying for the (doctoral program) **through** (given university).

Comment: Thanks so much. I have a further question: Is "I apply FOR a doctoral program" as common as "I apply TO a doctoral program"?